# how to resolve no test matches the given testcase filter azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mstest

[image]
Those unit test are executing in azure pipeline before swap. After executing everytime it's showing me this.

/TestAdapterPath:"F:\agents04_agent04\r2\a"
2023-10-12T20:10:01.1725408Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2023-10-12T20:10:04.1812614Z A total of 3 test files matched the specified pattern.
2023-10-12T20:10:04.2215572Z Blame: Attaching crash dump utility to process testhost.net472.x86 (19376).
2023-10-12T20:10:05.5133837Z No test matches the given testcase filter `TestCategory=BeforeSwap&TestCategory=prod&TestCategory=WebServices` in F:\agents04_agent04\r2\a\tests\DashboardApp.Deployment.Tests\DashboardApp.Deployment.Tests.dll F:\agents04_agent04\r2\a\tests\FtpLibrary.Tests\FtpLibrary.Tests.dll F:\agents04_agent04\r2\a\tests\Webservices.Deployment.Tests\Deployment.Tests.dll
2023-10-12T20:10:05.8662311Z Results File: F:\agents04_agent04_temp\TestResults\ga-build-vm$_ga-build-vm_2023-10-12_20_10_05.trx
2023-10-12T20:10:05.8907689Z Vstest.console.exe exited with code 0.
2023-10-12T20:10:05.8908174Z **************** Completed test execution *********************
2023-10-12T20:10:05.8970097Z Test results files: F:\agents04_agent04_temp\TestResults\ga-build-vm$_ga-build-vm_2023-10-12_20_10_05.trx
2023-10-12T20:10:05.9203010Z No Result Found to Publish 'F:\agents04_agent04_temp\TestResults\ga-build-vm$_ga-build-vm_2023-10-12_20_10_05.trx'.
2023-10-12T20:10:06.1745166Z Created test run: 1240217
2023-10-12T20:10:06.1747100Z Publishing test results: 0

I tried to update MSTest framework and adding MSTestAdapter.

Comment: Are those test category values enums? If so, what are the actual enum values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No test matches the given testcase filter TestCategory=BeforeSwap&TestCategory=prod&TestCategory=WebServices

Based on the error message, it indicates that the test categories in the test class or test method do not meet the test case filter you set in the Pipeline task.

The test category set in the test case filter needs to satisfy BeforeSwap, prod and webservice at the same time.

From your screenshot of the unit test code, the categories are BeforeSwap,prod  and Web API.

You can try to change the test case filter to the value: `TestCategory=BeforeSwap&TestCategory=prod&TestCategory=WebApi`

For example:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=BeforeSwap&TestCategory=prod&TestCategory=WebApi'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Or you can also check if the WebServices test category exists in your test categories definition and apply it to the actual test class.

Comment: variables:
  TestCategory.Environment: 'prod'
  TestCategory.Component: 'WebServices'

steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run before-swap tests'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*tests.dll
     !**\obj\**
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=BeforeSwap&TestCategory=$(TestCategory.Environment)&TestCategory=$(TestCategory.Component)'
    diagnosticsEnabled: True
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['DisableTests'], 'true'))

Comment: i did setup my YAML like this. but it doesn't work.

Comment: The value of the variable TestCategory.Component is WebServices. But the value is not match the test category in your test project(Based on the screenshot). Can you change the variable value to WebApi and check if it can work?  **TestCategory.Component: 'WebApi'**